# How to suspend or reduce throughput of Camel Hazelcast SEDA consumer in case of error

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast, hystrix

I have a Camel route consuming messages from a Hazelcast SEDA queue. In case of any error when processing a message, I want to reduce the consuming throughput in order to avoid moving lot of messages to a dead letter queue. I have been investigating hacking something by using http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html
with dynamic values and Circuit Breaker: http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html but without sucess.

Is there any other approach to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it another Camel Route of yours that sends messages to this Seda consumer? In that case you can use Throttler on that endpoint. Something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="....." />
  <throttle maximumRequestsPerPeriod="3" timePeriodMillis="10000">
    <to uri="hazelcast:seda:foo" />
  </throttle>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="hazelcast:seda:foo" />
  <to uri="....." />
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

To deliver this feature, I ended building my own (and first) Camel component:

https://github.com/rodolfodpk/camel-hz-queue